# How can I add a row between two rows in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've got a simple table, where I need to add an other row!
Now I want to add one more FS 5 between FS5 and the FS4.

How can I do that?

[image: This is a part of my table]

Comment: Rows are not ordered. You can specify SELECT order, but that's it.

Comment: Just add it in the end. You can always use `ORDER BY` in the query to put it in the desired location

Comment: why you need to add row between these two rows ? what is your purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert the rows then the rows are not ordered. What you can do is when you are selecting the row then you can use the `Order By` clause to get the row as you want.

Something like

```
SELECT column1,column12,column3 FROM dbo.MyTableName ORDER BY column1
```